# Prevent updating an unmounted component during async event handler

Tags: reactjs

I have an async event handler that deletes a component, but this component is using state to watch the event handler execution status. The event handler is a mock of deleting an item from a remote database.

The problem is that upon successful deletion, the component is unmounted, so the final state update (to indicate that deletion is done) triggers the error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component".

I understand that it is frequent classical issue, I would like to know what is the best way to solve it.

A sandbox:
[image: Edit SO-unruffled-bassi-2odi4]

The full code for reference:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [fruits, setFruits] = React.useState(["apple", "pear", "peach"]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {fruits.map((fruit) => (
        <Row key={fruit} fruit={fruit} setFruits={setFruits} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function Row({ fruit, setFruits }) {
  const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    setIsDeleting(true);
    try {
      await deleteFruit(fruit, setFruits);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occured");
    }
    setIsDeleting(false);
  };

  return (
    <li>
      {fruit}
      <button onClick={handleDelete} disabled={isDeleting}>
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}

async function deleteFruit(fruitToDelete, setFruits) {
  // mock remote DB
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFruits((fruits) => fruits.filter((f) => f !== fruitToDelete));
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

I have tried to prevent the issue by recording if the component is mounted with useRef and useEffect. It works, but I find that it is not easily readable. Is there a more explicit method to achieve this behaviour?

In component Row's render function:

```
const refIsMounted = React.useRef(true);

React.useEffect(() => {
  refIsMounted.current = true;
  return () => {
    refIsMounted.current = false;
  };
}, []);
```

And the async event handler:

```
if (refIsMounted.current) {
  setIsDeleting(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was the issue: **the lifetime of a component that triggers an async event handler is independent of the execution time of this async event handler**

So the solution is either:

- to put the state modified by the handler in a component which we know will outlive the handler, either higher in the component hierarchy or in Redux.
- to use the useRef trick as described above to check whether the triggering component is still in existence

Here I lifted the state in the parent component:
[image: Edit SO-unruffled-bassi-2odi4 (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

based on useEffect documents you can return a clean-up function.

> Often, effects create resources that need to be cleaned up before the
> component leaves the screen, such as a subscription or timer ID. To do
> this, the function passed to useEffect may return a clean-up function.

so your code will be like below:

```
useEffect(()=>{
      return ()=>{
            setIsDeleting(false);}
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not solves my issue in the case when deleteFruit fails to delete the item, because in this case, the Row is not unmounted, but I still want to update isDeleting to false.